# Add arguments to runnable jar file Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, swt

I have created little java program with SWT. 
For run it on Mac I need to use argument XstartOnFirstThread.
So from terminal I can start it like

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar progname.jar
```

Can I open this program using double click with this parameter? 
I know I may create script to run it, but is this possible without script?

Comment: As far as I can tell with the eclipse [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/), the answer is *no*.

Comment: Script is your best bet. There is no such direct way of doing it.

Comment: If you guys know, post an answer.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Alright :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201878/specifying-jvm-heap-sizes-in-jar).

The [answer posted by Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201926/1740724) states it outright: There is no way to pass the argument when starting the .jar by double-clicking.

However, there are alternatives:

1. The double click starts a wrapper program which then starts your program with the parameter (as suggested in the linked answer).
2. Create a script file that launches your application.
3. Create a [proper OSX application instead](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/).