# Setting Max Heap Size

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I want to set the maximum heap size of my application , now i am able to achieve that by specifying the max heap size in the running command like this :  java -jar  -Xmx1g app.jar

however i want to embed this information during the build process such that when i build it and run normally java -jar app.jar . it runs with a maximum set heap size

i tried to set jvmArgs in bootJar task but jvmArgs is not recognized as a property of bootJar

i also looked for any property to be added to application.preperties all i found was a way to set the max heap size during the build process

so is there any way to achieve that without explicitly mentioning the max size in the running command

so the desired sequence is :
1-./gradlew build
2- java -jar app.jar

then the running jar will have the desired max heap size

Comment: It's not possible to do what you are trying to achive.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201878/specifying-jvm-heap-sizes-in-jar